# Unbounded convex real functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, convex-analysis

Let $f$ be a real function defined on $[1, +\infty)$ and convex from a number on.

Is it true that the sequence $f_n:=f(n)$ is unbounded?

Comment: What about bounded above or below?( none-constant)

Comment: It is clear for constant, what about nonconstant functions?

Comment: What about $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no. Indeed, choose a constant function $f(x)=1$ for all $x\in[1,+\infty]$. It is convex and bounded.

Comment: No, things aren't "different" in the strict case. The answer is still no.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 yes indeed...